# How to use TIME type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, time

I'm building my first DB through MySQL Workbench.
In a table I need to store a `time` attribute that contains minutes and seconds.
In this regard, I wanted to use the `TIME` data type.
What is the argument required by the type `TIME(...)`?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved, I entered TIME without parentheses. I thought that the type TIME required an input parameter.

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CookingDB.Recipe (
  ...
  CookingTime TIME NULL,
  ...`

Answer (score 5):

As said in [MYSQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html):

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format

You have to use the [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) data type to represent the time of the day however to store only the minutes and seconds you need to use the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format your time in your desired format.

On a side note, do note that TIME datatype takes 3 bytes of space.